# How to implement the functionality of keeping the rectangle color while the mouse button is pressed in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML code that includes a rectangle. I want the rectangle to maintain its current color while the left mouse button is pressed and return to its original color when the button is released.

I have tried adding a MouseArea that detects when the button is pressed and changes the color of the rectangle, but this disrupts the original color of the rectangle. How can I modify my code to keep the current color of the rectangle while the left mouse button is pressed and return to the original color when the button is released?

Here is my current code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property string defaultColor: "#444"

    GridLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows: 2

        Repeater{
            model: 6
            delegate: Rectangle{
                color: defaultColor
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Text {
                    id: name
                    text: modelData
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "#eee"
                    font.pixelSize: 40
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }

                MouseArea{
                      anchors.fill: parent
                      acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton | Qt.LeftButton
                      onPressed: {
                          parent.color = this.pressedButtons === Qt.LeftButton ? "orange" : defaultColor
                      }
                  }

                  MouseArea{
                      anchors.fill: parent
                      acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton
                      hoverEnabled: true
                      onEntered: parent.color = 'orange'
                  }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

[image: img]

I want you to continue painting the cells in which my mouse enters but with the left button clicked here is an example in excel something similar
[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Rectangle {
        id: rectBtn; width: 100; height: 40
        color: mouseArea.pressed ? "gray" : "orange";
        Text {anchors.centerIn: parent;text: qsTr("Click")}
        MouseArea {id: mouseArea;anchors.fill: parent}
    }
```

// ++++++++++ OR ++++++++++++++++

```
    Button {
        text: "Click"; width: 100; height: 40
        background: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: parent.down ? "gray" : "orange";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your solution. Instead of labels, are you suggesting to create buttons? I think that would generate the same problem.

Comment: This answer looks correct, but it can be improved with an explanation rather than just dropping code. See in the first code block, the Rectangle's color property is dependent on the `mouseArea.pressed` property. That's how you change the color based on the state of your mouse press.

Comment: @JarMan I don't think that was misunderstood, I need the color to remain in the labels where the mouse leaves and generate a new color in the labels where the mouse enters when pressed, that is, my second MouseArea is perfect but I need the button clicked

Comment: (onPressed: {} Press the mouse on the control) , 
(onReleased:  {} Release the mouse from the control) , 
(onEntered: {} Entering the mouse on the control) , 
(onExited:  {} Mouse out of control) ,

Comment: If you set hoverEnabled: true, activation of mouse entry and exit events from the control will not require clicking

Comment: You can also use the onPositionChanged and onMouseXChanged events.

Answer (score 0):

This code works like the first photo, and after clicking on the control, its color changes, and after the mouse leaves the control, this color remains, and when the mouse is clicked again, its color returns to its original state.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectBtn; width: 100; height: 100
    color: "#444444"
    Text {anchors.centerIn: parent;text: qsTr("Click");color: "white";}
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea;anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.color == "#444444" ? parent.color = "#ff8419" : parent.color = "#444444"
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for multiple controls.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent; objectName: "objMouse";
    onClicked: {
        var child = grid.childAt(mouse.x,mouse.y);
        if( child.color == "#444444")
            child.color = "#ff8419";
        else
            child.color = "#444444";
    }
}
    GridLayout {
        id:  grid;
        columns: 2; rows: 2; columnSpacing: 5; rowSpacing: 5;
        Rectangle { color: "#444444"; width: 100; height: 100;}
        Rectangle { color: "#444444"; width: 100; height: 100 ;  }
        Rectangle { color: "#444444"; width: 100; height: 100; }
        Rectangle { color: "#444444"; width: 100; height: 100 ;}
    }
```